# Direct collocation determinism

Tags: drake

Is the direct collocation algorithm deterministic (specifically using the SNOPT solver)? I've created a direct collocation optimization problem and occasionally the optimization will instantly fail (sometimes several times in a row) due to invalid direct collocation constraints. Eventually I can get the optimization to begin running by restarting my script (usually several times in a row). I thought both the direct collocation algorithm and the SNOPT optimizer were deterministic, but this makes me think otherwise

Comment: The algorithm is deterministic, but I am not sure if the implementation is.

For example, if you have a std::unordered_set and then loop within that unordered_set, the order of traversing the element in the set is not deterministic.

In Drake, we have tried to make sure that the MathematicalProgram is deterministic. If you have a reproducible code that shows non-determinism, please let us know and file a Drake github issue. Thanks!